# Factory or constructor - where to set object properties?

Tags: php, constructor, factory

I am a little bit confused about, what is the right place to set object properties, in constructor or in factory method, or it does not matter?

In constructor:

```
class Foo {
    public $bar;
    function __constructor($b) {
        $this->bar = $b;
    }

    static function factory($b) {
        return new self($b);
    }
}
```

In factory:

```
class Foo {
    public $bar;    

    static function factory($b) {
        $obj = new self();
        $obj->bar = $b;
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example factory method and constructor do same things. For your code it is no matter.

Comment: As far as the factory is concerned, it makes no difference, because it's encapsulated :)

Comment: Why exactly would you want to use a factory method to return `self` at all?

Comment: @vzwick This was just an example to demonstrate my question. But in real world I like to use the pattern: Class::factory()->do_something()->do_something_else(), instead of $c = new Class(); $c->do_something()->do_something_else().

Comment: Hum. I always thought that the factory pattern was supposed to enable conditional post-loading of classes at runtime ... Never thought about it as a way to save yourself the additional line for the assignment.

Comment: @vzwick Yes it was, but you can use it for other purposes too. I don't think it is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is can you instantiate the class without setting the **b** property. If it will work, you do not need to set the property in the constructor. If the property is important for others method to work, you have to set it in the constructor. Factory has nothing to do with this. If the factory was the only way to instantiate the class (the constructor was private), then the code would be encapsulated, but still you need to pass the required parameters to the constructor, otherwise you can easly forget about them when you refactor your code.